# Does making regular, say every 1 min HTTP Restful calls cacheble and leading to memory leaks?

Tags: rest, http, put

If I have cron job that sends HTTP put to another service on a regular basis, will that service eventually crash due to some sort of caching going on? I thought RESTful means stateless so that there is no record of anything stored. Please correct me if I am incorrect.

Comment: it would be a poorly written service if it couldn't sustain 1 request/minute.  Not really sure what you are asking here.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not constant requests to another service would cause issues would depend entirely on how that service was programmed.

There is nothing about REST in general that suggests many requests would cause any issues.  That doesn't prevent any particular service from having an implementation bug which causes problems though.

Comment: Could you give example of bad or good Restful implementation that, if called in a regular CRON job would cause memory leak, if at all possible.